# How to get the specific <Ad ID, Campaign ID> that was clicked on from the landing page?

Tags: google-ads-api

I've been searching for a solution to this, which I thought would be trivial, and seems pretty much impossible.

Here's the situation: I set up an AdWords campaign, ad groups and ads. I point them to www.mysite.com

Once visitors arrive to my site through one of my ads, I want to know which exact ad they clicked on (and campaign, as apparently the ad id isn't globally unqiue). Is this possible?

I first tried by enabling Destination URL auto-tagging, but seems like the gclid parameter is pretty much useless.

Then I looked at the UTMZ cookie, but it seems like at most (correct me if this isn't the case), you get the campaign number (is this even the ID in AdWords?) and the keywords searched or the ad's keywords, one of those. Not anything I can uniquely identify the ad by, right?

Finally, I looked at ValueTrack, although again correct me if I'm wrong, but this would mean manually changing the destination URL of each of my ads in AdWords, right? Even doing this, I'm not sure I can get something that lets me uniquely identify the clicked ad. Is {creative} what I want? It's described in the docs as the "unique ID of the creative", does that mean this includes the Campaign.Id and the AdGroupAd.Id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to do what you want using tracking templates.

## Navigating to auto-tracking and tracking template settings:

1. Log in to Adwords, and click "Campaigns".
2. Click "Shared Library" in the bottom left corner.
3. Under "Shared Library", click "URL options".
   [image]
4. You'll now get these options:
   [image: URL Options screenshot, with options "Tracking template" and "Auto-tagging"]

These options are set for the entire account. I think it is possible to override the tracking template for individual campaigns, ad groups and ads. Here is what they mean:

## Auto-tagging

*Auto-tagging* means that when a user clicks on an ad, they will go a URL with the `gclid` parameter appended, for example `http://yourwebsite.com/?gclid=example`. This value is useful for some things, such as for offline conversions, so your website should save it.

## Tracking template

*Tracking template* means that when a user clicks on an ad, they will be directed to this URL. Interestingly, it does *not* have to be your website, as long as the URL redirects to your website. For instance, you could set it up to look like this:

```
http://trackingcompany.com/?url={lpurl}&campaignid={campaignid}
```

`{lpurl}` and `{campaignid}` are placeholders which AdWords recognises and knows how to handle. So, for example, if a user clicks on an ad, they could go to:

```
http://trackingcompany.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com&campaignid=543987
```

`trackingcompany.com` must redirect the user now to `http://yourwebsite.com`, otherwise, it is in violation of AdWords policy and your ads could be rejected.

Now, here's the clever bit that I didn't realise because all of this is badly documented: you don't have to use a third-party tracking company to get access to things like campaign id. You can just reuse your own website! Just set your tracking URL to something like this:

```
{lpurl}?campaignid={campaignid}
```

You see that? `{lpurl}` will get replaced with the landing page, which is your website! So the user in our example would go to this URL upon clicking an ad:

```
http://yourwebsite.com?campaignid=543987
```

It's not clear to me whether `example.com` must now redirect to the landing page URL without those parameters, or not.

I can't find documentation on these placeholders anywhere, but these are the ones that I've found work:

- `{lpurl}` landing page URL
- `{campaignid}` campaign ID
- `{adgroupid}` ad group ID
- `{creative}` creative or ad ID
- `{keyword}` keyword

## Auto-tagging and tracking template together

If you enable both auto-tagging and a tracking template, then AdWords would behave as it normally does with a tracking template, appending a `gclid` query parameter.

---

#### Addendum: ignoring these new query parameters in Google Analytics:

If you use Google Analytics, you probably want to ignore these query parameters, merging hits with these parameters with hits that don't have them. You can do that by setting the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" option to `aw_campaignid,aw_adgroupid,aw_creative,aw_keyword`. You can't apply this retroactively, so do this before making any AdWords changes.

[image: Screenshot of Exclude URL Query Parameters option]

Comment: Here's the full list of possible parameters for the tracking template: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348

Comment: @amann Is it possible to use more than 1 tracking template at the same time? I'm looking to use a remote tracking template (ad.atdmt.com) and {lpurl}?campaignid={campaignid} at the same time. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no value track for campaign or ad group ID.  You could just append something to the end of each ad's destination URL based on the campaign & ad group, but that is a bit of a chore.

If you [link your Google Analytics & AdWords accounts](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en-GB) and use auto-tagging in AdWords you can get the information you want in GA through the AdWords report (shows campaign, ad group, keyword etc).  GA is able to use the gclid to retrieve data from AdWords, and I think you can then use the GA API to get the campaign data back out if you want it.

Comment: I also didn't want to link Analytics and AdWords.. but doing that, am I going to be able to programmatically get the the specific ad that was clicked by the current visitors (I don't want aggregated data, I care about the current visitor in real time)? Seems like the only way is adding some unique parameter at the end of each ad :(

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. turn off auto-tagging
2. pull the entire account into an excel file
3. insert a new column for each desired output variable (Campaign, ad id [like Headline?])
4. trim, lower, and find/remove spaces from the target columns (so something like: campaignname, compressedheadline)
5. then concatenate that column with your destination URLs and a UTM string like this:
   ?utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_content=compressedheadline&utm_campaign=campaignname
6. use this function and replace with the appropriate columns
   =concatenate([dest url column],"?utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_content=",[compressedheadline column],"&utm_campaign=",[campaignname column])
7. if the functions for the parts between the quotes break the formula, paste them into their own cells and then reference the cells in the concatenate function.
8. Drag this formula down the entire account,
9. Copy / Paste Special / Paste Values of the new Destination URLs over the old Destination URLs.
10. Remove unnecessary columns that have been created between Campaign, Ad Group, Headline, Description Line 1, Description Line 2, Display URL and your new Destination URL.
11. Then highlight just the Campaign, Ad Group, Headline, Description Line 1, Description Line 2, Display URL and your new Destination URL and you can paste this into the AdWords Editor under "add/update multiple ads.

Comment: Well, if I wanted to do it manually I could just add a ?mySpecialUniqueParam=[unique ad identifier her] to the destination URL  of each of my ads, but I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: I just meant that path is your best option to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data from the CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT - The only downside to this, is that this report can only be run for 1 day. so if you needed a month worth of data - you would have to run about 30 reports -

The ad Id is the "CreativeId" - you can get the campaignId and Adgroup ID as well from this report - there is 1 row for each click - (GCLID) these are unique.

see this link for more info on what fields are available

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#click

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question, as I need to know the ad that was clicked on the landing page the user arrives at, not after the fact on a click performance report.